# Converting factor variables to numeric ones by replacing blanks cells to NA or changing them to "."

Tags: r, dataset, missing-data

1. I want to convert some factor variables to numeric variables by this code:

```
    df$col <- as.numeric(df$col)
```

2. The missing values in my dataset are not represented by a dot (i.e., "."). Instead, they are blank cells.
3. Therefore, the above code allocates a number (i.e., "1") to each blank cells in my dataset.
4. My question is how I can convert factor variables to numeric ones by replacing blanks cells to NA or changing them to ".".

Thank you so much.

Comment: Please edit your question following these [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: @jay.sf that question solves part of the problem. There's the blank/NA cells to consider. If you can find a duplicate question that answers coercing from factor and blank cells, we can close it as that.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik That might be not entirely true since these "blank cells" probably also are converted into a factor level. Using the linked answer should yield correctly `NA`.

Answer (score 1):

The right way to go about this is to use NA for missing values.
In order to convert a factor to numeric, you will have to first coerce to character. But first, replace blank cells with NAs.

```
x <- factor(c("1", ""))
x[x == ""] <- NA
as.numeric(as.character(x))
[1]  1 NA
```

Comment: Try `as.numeric(as.character(factor(c("1", ""))))`.

Comment: This code also gave the value 1 to the blank cells.

Comment: @ND2020 did you convert the blank cell to NA before coercing to numeric? If yes, I'd like to see a reproducible example at this point.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik I found a function to address it. The function `unfactor()` converts to character data type first and then converts back to numeric. As a result, blank cells are replaced with NA.